# can you insert a string into another string by user input in python?

Tags: python, string, input, insert

please someone help me!
I am trying to make a simple program where the user can insert a string into an already existing string(sorry if that's confusing!)

this is my code:

```
firststring = input("enter a string: ")
secondstring = input("enter a second string: ")
position = input("where would you like to place the second string?")
if possition.isdigit == True:
    print() <--#help me here
```

so can someone please help me?

Comment: Well you can't insert a string inside another string as strings are *immutable*. You need to take slices of strings based on position and concatenate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use string slicing to print the first part of the first string, then the second string, then the remainder of the first string.

```
position = int(input("where would you like to place the second string?"))
print(firststring[:position] + secondstring + firststring[position:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with list slicing. `firststring[:int(position)]` will get all characters till specific index, then concantenate the second string and `firststring[int(position):]` will get all characters from the index position to the end

```
position = input("where would you like to place the second string?")
if position.isdigit() :
    string3=firststring[:int(position)]+secondstring+firststring[int(position):]
    print(string3)
```